# install erro in Composer-Setup to laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

when I install Composer-Setup i have this error message . so what is the problem : 
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly. Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:  The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the SSL extension in the PHP running at the command line. Note that this is not the PHP running inside your Apache.

Run `php -i` on the command line to see which extensions are enabled and which `php.ini` is being used for the command line. Edit this to enable the SSL extension, or install it in case it is a separate package on your OS.